# Can't access home directory during boot. Any solutions?

Tags: 14.04, boot, google-chrome, encryption

I recently switched to Ubuntu 14.04 from windows. I've setup Chrome Remote Desktop but it won't start during the boot process and the following error appears in boot.log

```
 * Starting Chrome Remote Desktop host for saurabh...       [170G 
[164G[ OK ]
 * speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned
 * Restoring resolver state...       [170G 
[164G[ OK ]
 * Stopping save kernel messages[164G[ OK ]
Failed to load config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/saurabh/.config/chrome-remote-desktop/host#ba729066861c0767fb62791c78a5aeac.json'
2015-02-05 15:31:36,819:INFO:Cleanup.
```

I was also trying to run another program, which was saved in my documents folder, from rc.local. It failed too because of the same reason.

I've encrypted my home folder. Could that be reason for these failures? If not, does anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Your home won't decrypt and mount until you log in.

You want to move this script to [start when you log in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login).

Answer (score 0):

you will need to do additional work to setup Chrome Remote Desktop for Linux (beta by the way).  Instructions are here:

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1649523?hl=en

Set up Chrome Remote Desktop -> Enable remote access to your computer - Linux (Beta)